# An I being downvoted because people think I'm evil?

Tags: discussion

[Is there a state, individual or communal, perhaps a virtue, that cannot be touched by any tragedy?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97128/is-there-a-state-individual-or-communal-perhaps-a-virtue-that-cannot-be-touch?noredirect=1#comment280798_97128)

I find that idea very unsettling; I can assure you I am not evil! Why not just downvote anyone who seems mentally ill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *a lot* of posts just like this one asking for explanations for a particular downvote. My best advice is: Ignore them. Some people just hit it when they do not understand the question, consider it not answerable objectively, or think it is based on wrong premises. And all of these are, in principle, valid reasons to vote down. Also, there is no obligation to explain downvotes, like at all.

I understand it would be *nice* for people, especially those suffering mental illnesses, to be able to have a clear explanation so that they can better fight the tendency of attributing this on some negative, assumed attribute of oneself.

In the end, most of the times a downvote is simply irrelevant and the main reason lies with the person casting it. Therefore, it makes no sense to lose more than a passing thought on them.

Comment: yeah, thanks for sympathetic response. strange times and i should have deleted already

Comment: i think part of the problem here - and it can't be peculiar to me - is people voting based on a hunch, an intuitive judgment something isn't quite right. which, due to their lack of familiarity with the site, they then fail to explain

Comment: @identicon But even that is, in principle, ok. The main problem here is that, other than on other sites of the network, people do not vote enough so that downvotes have impact way above proportionality. That, in turn, is not the fault of those who legitimately vote down what they think is bad (not everyone can be held to ideal standards), it is the one of those who (should) know better and do *not* vote to put the downvote(s) into perspective.

Comment: yeah. well you're a good admin, so don't let it bother you. any interesting stuff with stoicism and critical theory, btw? i can actually google that though, now :)